# JavaScript Comma Operator Removal

Tags: javascript

Which tool is able to remove js comma operator expressions reliably?
Is there free software available?

```
// comma operator
return (1,2);

// comma operator removed
1;
return 2;
```

**Edit:**

Transpilation might be error prone! What option is there to do this without switching to a meta language or transpiling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use compilers like [CoffeeScript](https://coffeescript.org/#introduction) or [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/) to do that.

Comment: What CoffeeScript command will transform a input.js into a output.js without comma operator?